# Ошибка при подключении JFramework

Tags: joomla

Имеется сайт на локальном сервере. Создаю php-скрипт, вызываемый при помощи AJAX. В начале пишу такие строки:

```
define('_JEXEC', 1);
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/includes/defines.php');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/includes/framework.php');
```

В дальнейшем необходимо вызывать методы объекта JFactory. Открываю скрипт - белый экран с ошибками:

> Warning: require_once(JPATH_BASE\libraries/import.legacy.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in W:\domains\site.ru\includes\framework.php on line 15
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'JPATH_BASE\libraries/import.legacy.php'

Что не так делаю?

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но возможно не определено JPATH_BASE или определено неправильно, говорит же что не может найти файл.
Попробуйте
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('JPATH_BASE', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DS . '');

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.

Comment: @binliz, преобразовали бы вы, что ли, комментарий в ответ...